# Best way to implement "CSS like" views positioning in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to build an SDK which allow publishers to design my ads according to their native UI. More specifically if you look at the example I took from Google Native Express Ads:

[image]

I want to use a configuration file to be able to set:

1. each component position, for example the "install" button at the top or bottom, text on top of image or below image, etc, etc.
2. The size of the Ad container

I tried to implement it with a xib which contains all the components and then try to set it in run-time with constraints according to some configurations file - I got to say it's not going well so far.

I also looked at Facebook ComponentKit (http://componentkit.org/) but it seems to be more suitable for UITableView and not for 1 generic view.

What do you think is the best way to approach this challenge? Is there any OOTB solution you'd recommend? Any sample projects that done similar thing?

Thanks,

Comment: If you like CSS, why not use CSS (and a web view)? That in fact is what Apple does in a similar situation (i.e. the iTunes store interface).

Comment: I second @matt's suggestion. However, If you really want to use constraints, and you already know which views are going to be around, you can serialize all your constrains in visual format form and deliver them to the app, which will mindlessly create those constraints. Say, a json response with an array of strings.

Comment: @FernandoMazzon That's a clever idea. I never thought about visual format strings as being a readily network-communicable way of encoding constraints.

Comment: @matt I have to implement the views natively. fernando that's a creative solution but creates coupling between iOS and server.

Answer (score -1):

You can implementier your own Viewcontroller by inheriting from UIViewController. Then you can overwrite the method ViewDidLayoutSubviews. In this method you can set the position of the ui element on the view. This can be done relative röntge complete size. Herr is some example Code in C#:

```
        /// </summary>
    public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

        var tempFrame = View.Frame;

        _settings.Frame = new CGRect(tempFrame.Width * 0.25, tempFrame.Height * 0.25, tempFrame.Width * 0.06, tempFrame.Height * 0.6);
        _statistics.Frame = new CGRect(tempFrame.Width * 0.75, tempFrame.Height * 0.25, tempFrame.Width * 0.06, tempFrame.Height * 0.6);
    }
```

As you can See the Position is calculated dynamically. Just add a method to your view controller that takes the position (e.g. as enum) an calculate the real postion for the element(s).